# How to update a Frame in Tkinter in a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, multiprocessing

I'm trying to create a status bar that checks if a connection to the internet is present.

I have imported

```
from multiprocessing import Process
```

and I created a function in a class:

```
def check_connection(self):
    while True:
        time.sleep(3)
        try:
            urllib.request.urlopen('http://216.58.192.142')
            stato_conn = Label(self.bottom_uno_frame,text="Ok connection")
            stato_conn.pack(side=RIGHT)
            stato_conn.after(1000, lambda: stato_conn.destroy())

        except IndexError as err:
            stato_conn = Label(self.bottom_uno_frame, text="Connection down")
            stato_conn.pack(side=RIGHT)
            stato_conn.after(1000, lambda: stato_conn.destroy())
```

Then I was trying to launch it in `__init__`:

```
p1 = Process(target=self.check_connection())
p1.start()
```

But it doesn't work.

This is my app in Tkinter. I'm trying to create a label in the bottom frame "Status bar" that checks every 3 seconds if there is a valid internet connection.

If true label text= Connection ok, if false label text=Connection down

[image: app in tkinter]

Comment: It seems you want to access `tkinter` widgets from **two** `Process`, please confirm?

Comment: Yes, I think it is the only way

Comment: ***"Yes, I think it is the only way"***: This is not possible, you have to implement some sort of [Inter-process_communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) to do so.

Comment: Suggestions ???

Comment: Read through this list [`[python][tkinter] queue`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isanswered%3Ayes+is%3Aquestion+%5Bpython%5D%5Btkinter%5D+queue) but keep in mind these are all `threading` examples you have to use the `multiprocessing` ones.

Comment: `p1 = Process(target=self.check_connection())` should be `p1 = Process(target=self.check_connection)` (without ending ()).  And why do you catch `IndexError`?  Should `URLError` be used?

Comment: As you cannot access the tkinter widgets in another process, you should use `multiprocessing.SimpleQueue` to exchange data between processes.  Also you can use `thread` instead of another process.